# Writing sequences program in Java using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, sequences

I've been tasked with a problem that finds all the subsequences for a string.

For example, if the string is "bat" the subsequences returns [,b, ba, at, bt, t]

Notice how it doesn't have all the permutations of the string since it has to go in order. The first string is an empty string and that's apparently requires by the instructions.

Another example is the string "brat". The expected output for that would be [, a, at, b, ba, bat, br, bra, brat, brt, bt, r, ra, rat, rt, t]

I've tried to write a program that would use recursion and give me the output but I've only gotten so far. I'm sure I understand recursion but I don't know how I would try to code this problem.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Sequences {
   public static ArrayList<String> sequences(String s) {
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();      
      return subsequences(s, list);
   }
   public static ArrayList<String> sequences(String s, ArrayList<String> list) {
       list.add("");
       if (s.length() == 0) 
           list.add(s);
       else {
           list.add(s);
           String temp = s.substring(0,1);
           String next = s.substring(1, s.length());
           list.add(temp);
           sequences(next);
       }
       return list;
   }
}
```

I also wrote a tester really quickly so I can test the problem since a tester wasn't provided to us:

```
  public class tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Sequences.sequences("at"));
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is [, a] when I should have gotten [,a, at, t]

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Remember that you can pass around the ArrayList and modify it. Otherwise you're making a new list at every level of recursion, which is what you're doing, in fact... If you pass it as a parameter you can then modify it. You don't really need to send it back because objects are passed in Java by reference, not by value (or maybe it's the other way around, but the point is that you get to work on the same object)...

Comment: I am not getting why you are creating the list again and again in the method. Think about it once..

Comment: Would making a recursive method help? That way I make the arraylist in the original method and then pass the list to the helper method?

Comment: Okay I modified my code so that it only creates an arraylist one time. Now I get the output as [,a,at]. The t is missing in there. How do I fix that?

Comment: @watabou Still you are calling sequences(next), even after changing the parameters. Also do something with the return types.

Comment: @sans481 I'm sorry but I don't know what you are trying to say...Do you mean I shouldn't call sequences(next)? I have that for recursion. And do you mean I should change it to void for the helper method? I wasn't sure...

Comment: @sans481 Okay I think I might have solved this one... I removed sequences(next) and just added in list.add(next) and it gives me back the output of [,a,at,t]... Now to check if it works for longer strings.

Comment: Join- http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8227/writing-sequences-program-in-java-using-recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong. One solution to the problem is this:

In each step of recursion, put aside the first character and compute all subsequences of the rest. Then add all of the computed subsequences twice: once without the first character and another time with prepending the character.

```
public class Sequences {

    public static ArrayList<String> sequences(String s) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            list.add("");
            return list;
        }
        String firstChar = s.substring(0, 1);
        String theRest = s.substring(1, s.length());
        ArrayList<String> siffixSequence = sequences(theRest);
        list.addAll(siffixSequence);
        for (String string : siffixSequence) {
            list.add(firstChar + string);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Sequences.sequences("brat"));
        // prints [, t, a, at, r, rt, ra, rat, b, bt, ba, bat, br, brt, bra, brat]
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool, I knew I was close to the answer. I checked out another answer here in stackoverflow about powerset and I got something else. All I had to do was change assign the recursion to another arraylist and add that to the first arraylist. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Mehdi, just FYI, providing complete solutions to homework problems isn't always appropriate.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812 gives general advice on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

You're not *doing* anything with `sequences(next)` in the recursion.  If you can figure out what to do with it, you'll be set.

Comment: I thought that was for recursion. I set it so that it passes the substring(1, s.length()) to itself and in my young programming mind, there is nothing wrong with that. Can you please explain further?

Comment: `sequences(next)` returns a _result_, but you're not using it in any way.  You're calling it correctly, sure, but then you have to do something with the list it returns.

Comment: Oh. I think you mean I should store it in a variable. But since it returns an arraylist of type string, would I have to make another arraylist and add the result in that list?

Comment: Something along those lines.  Good luck! ;)